# "Für einen Moment" vs "Im Moment"

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

> Für einen Moment schaue ich auf die Uhr, die 16 Uhr zeigt.
>
> Im Moment schaue ich auf die Uhr, die 16 Uhr zeigt.

Ich habe dieses in einem Taschenbuch gelesen und frage mich, ob sie das gleiche sind. Danke!

Comment: Beide Sätze klingen auf jeden Fall so, als ob es dort mehrere Uhren gibt. Eine, die 16 Uhr zeigt, eine, die 17 Uhr zeigt, eine, die 18 Uhr zeigt, .......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Für einen Moment" bedeutet, daß die Handlung (oft auch das Empfinden) nur kurz andauert. "Im Moment" bedeutet, daß die Handlung gerade eben stattfindet und eventuell noch länger andauern kann, bezeichnet also den Zeitpunkt.